# How to re-run random. in the instantiation of a child class in python?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, random, instantiation

So I'm trying to create a method in a parent class that requires an attribute that is a random integer in between (number a) and (number b), the value being instantiated before hand. But for each child class I want to instantiate a different random integer in between different numbers, say (number c) and (number d). It kind of works generating numbers for each class differently but each time the method runs for the classes, the instantiated number is the saved as the same number for each class without every re-randomizing. I want it to randomize each time the method is called.

```
import random

class Parent:
  def __init__(self):
    self.random = random.randint(1, 10)

  def randomize(self):
     print(self.random)

class Child(Parent):
  def __init__(self):
    self.random = random.randint(11, 20)

a = Parent()
b = Child()

a.randomize()
a.randomize()
a.randomize()

b.randomize()
b.randomize()
b.randomize()
```

First Output:

```
9
9
9
15
15
15
```

Second Output:

```
3
3
3
19
19
19
```

I want each time the method is called to randomize a different number while having different ranges for the number to be randomized from for each class. The goal is to not have to copy/past the method to each class a different .randint hardcoded in.

Comment: Why don't you just store the min and max when initialising, then return a new random number from the method? Maybe they should be class attributes, or these should be instances not classes, it's not clear what your actual context is.

Comment: In your method, *you have to call `random.randint(1, 10)`*. Maybe assign the value back to `self.random`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See @johnsharpe's comment.  You should put the lower and upper bounds as parameters and then call `random.randint` each time you want to randomize.

```
import random

class Parent:
  def __init__(self, a=1, b=10):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    self.random = random.randint(self.a, self.b)

  def randomize(self):
    self.random = random.randint(self.a, self.b)
    print(self.random)

class Child(Parent):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(11, 20)
```

Comment: That came to mind, but then the next question is: why is `Child` a class at all, instead of just `b = Parent(11, 20)`?

Comment: I am not sure what else is being implemented in the child class, so I assume there are other features that are not present in the parent class

Comment: Whenever I assign a variable to a child class I wanted to not have to redefine the range it could pull from. I wanted it to be already defined, each range being different for each child class. This does seem to be the solution I was looking for. Sorry if the question wasn't very clear or if I should've added more context. I'm very new to both python and StackOverflow, so I may need to just continue refining more basic concepts in the future.

I appreciate the help!